# Need Help understanding A basic programming core concept about (AND)

Tags: php

So I am a beginner in programming I just started PHP and I was doing a programming challenge in which I had to write a program that would tell if a number entered is power of 2 or not, anyways after finishing the challenge I saw the answer and then their code was much more simple and well how would I say it it was more elegant.

here it is

```
if(($n & ($n - 1)) == 0)  
{  
    return "$n is power of 2";  
}
```

now what I don't understand is that how does ANDing , lets say 3 with 2 tell me if 3 is a power of two or not ??

ACTUALLY I THINK I DONT UNDERSTAND $n AND ($n-1) ==0 then its power of 2 I dont understand that formula  " if its a formula " like comparing the binaries of both of them and then if the result is a no then its power of two just doesn't make sense

Comment: write out the numbers and do the binary math.

Comment: I've done that but what I need to understand is that why , WHY when I AND 3 with 2 i.e N with (N-1) and I get 0 in return :  It means that its a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Lets get some **examples**

2 in binary is 10

(2-1) = 1 in binary is 1

`&` is logical or - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

    `10
and 01
=   00`

**Next example with 4**

4 in binary is 100

(4-1) = 3 in binary is 11

     `100
and  011
is   000`

8 in binary is 1000

7 in binary is 0111

1000 and 0111 = 0

See the table of power of two

[image]

As you can see all powers of 2 have the following format: 1 followed by 0 many times ( regex /10+/ )
The n-1 is 01111

This way you always have

    `100000000....
and 011111111....`

Comment: maybe my question isn't clear I understand this perfectly fine .... but what I don't undeerstand is the logic of this if statement I mean why is it that if its equal to two then its a power of 2 WHy so ? I guess Maybe I wanna ask about this Formula I just can't seem to get my question out there I understand that the program is saying if its equal to 0 then power of two and if not then its not  power of two ..... but what is the back end logic what makes it power of 2 if 4 & 3 ==0 why isn't it power of 4 or 5 or anything why 2 .

Comment: Well you can clearly see from the table above from the bit patterns and the formula that it works... 2, 4 and 8 are powers of 2. The rest cannot be obtained from 2^x = y ie what would x be to get 5? It's not a power of 2. It's really neat :)